# Can I handle an error from the gapi.client.load's promise?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, promise, google-cloud-endpoints

Question if [gapi.client.load](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientload) returns the promise was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901570/can-gapi-client-load-for-cloud-endpoints-return-a-promise). And as [Mike Witt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775513/mike-witt) answered, the code:

```
gapi.client.load('guestbook', 'v1', undefined, '/_ah/api');
```

returns the promise, but **without any error callback function**.

I tried to handle the error:

```
gapi.client.load('guestbook', 'v1', undefined, '/_ah/api')
  .then(
     function() {
       //success
     },
     function(error) {
       //error
     }
  );
```

and when I turn off an endpoint module it will never steps into the error handler. I'm only getting a following error in a console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-s…3DIQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOu-PQv0yFB8pB9mX2w3nuej8rl5Q net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  cb=gapi.loaded_0:163
```

*Is there any way how to handle this error?* I've tried to find it in docs, but without success.

Comment: Given that the callback parameter seems not to be called on errors either, this might simply be ignored. Which is bad design of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time I have found the answer:

```
gapi.client.load('guestbook', 'v1', undefined, '/_ah/api')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if(response && response.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
         // error
      } else {
         // success
      }
    }
  );
```

In the case of some error, the **gapi.client.load** returns an error object e.g.:

```
{error: {errors: Array[1], code: 404, message: "Not Found"}}
```

but it has to be "caught" in the *.then()* not in the *.catch()*

Comment: It doesn't work. Please see this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/16apcttb/4/

Comment: @DFB just like your jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test for a fail (at least now). I am pretty sure this is what you are looking for.

Here is the code:

```
gapi.client.init({}).then(() => {
     gapi.client.load('some-api', "v1", (err) => { callback(err) }, "https://someapi.appspot.com/_ah/api");
}, err, err);

function callback(loadErr) {
    if (loadErr) { err(loadErr); return; }
    // success code here 
}

function err(err){
     console.log('Error: ', err);
     // fail code here
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/n1fyqopr/)

Comment: I have tried this with endpoints API. If the API is unavailable (server down), callback function is not invoked at all. You can check the result in this fiddle where I used localhost for the endpoints URL: https://jsfiddle.net/yosj1d4z/

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for this method is : gapi.client.load(API_NAME, API_VERSION, CALLBACK);

you might have a look here [1], also this stackoverflow question can help you [2].

'/_ah/api' cannot be used as a callback as it is a specific handler for testing and viewing APIs of your Google App, for example when using endpoints for mobile applications.

[1] https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript#OptionLoadtheserviceAPIthenassembletherequest

[2] [Catch Error from gapi.client.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563863/catch-error-from-gapi-client-load)

Comment: You can also use this method with four parameters as I mentioned in the question or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901570/can-gapi-client-load-for-cloud-endpoints-return-a-promise). With this combination of parameters I can achieve that _load_ method returns the promise. My problem is that the promise is never rejected when something goes wrong during the endpoint loading.